# Is Deutoronomy 25:4 an interpolation?

Tags: 1-corinthians, numbers, deuteronomy

Deutoronomy 25:4 NKJV

> 4 “You shall not muzzle an ox while it treads out  the grain.

All the verses in this chapter are related except this one.There are ample places where this text could have fitted perfectly (Numbers 18:21,Numbers 18:26,Deutoronomy 14:28) corresponding with tithing and fiscal support of the levites.

Why this quote was sandwiched between the miscellaneous laws of flogging guilty men and the levirate marriages is a little baffling.All the verses in this chapter are interconnected except this one which seems out of place.

When Paul quotes this text (1 Corinthians 9:7-14) he uses it to buttress his argument about the fiscal support for the ministry which is clearly in context within the chapter

Here in Deutoronomy it stands out alone without any contextual support whatsoever

Could this have been a later edition or wrongly placed in this chapter?

Comment: Is this a hermeneutics question?

Comment: Do you have any evidence supporting this?

Answer (score 2):

If you bear it in mind that the bible was not originally written in chapters and verses then the verse you sighted above wouldn't seem to be out of place. 
Chapter 24 talked about laws concerning marriage, divorce,oppression of servants,perversion of judgement,lending ,pledging,stealing ,planting,harvest,gleaning and then flows into chapter 25 with judgement and punishment and then talks about not muzzling the ox when it treads out the corn(which is related to the topic of planting and harvesting discussed towards the end of the previous chapter).

Now, if you also understand that the verse you mentioned is not just about oxen and grains but also about being fair and considerate when dealing with people especially employees then the verse wouldn't seem so much out of place since the sum of chapter 24 and 25 is about being fair and considerate in one's dealings with people.